# Separating every second digit in an integer C++

Tags: c++, string, numbers, boolean

I am currently finishing up an assignment I have to complete for my OOP class and I am struggling with 1 part in particular. Keep in mind I am still a beginner. The question is as followed:

If the string contains 13 characters, all of characters are digits and the check digit is modulo 10, this function returns true; false otherwise.

This is in regards to a EAN. I basically have to separate every second digit from the rest digits. for example 9780003194876 I need to do calculations with 7,0,0,1,4,7. I have no clue about doing this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
bool isValid(const char* str){
if (atoi(str) == 13){

}

return false;
}
```

Comment: `atoi()` converts a byte string to an integer. Comparing the result with 13 is checking if `str` contains `"13"`. If you needed to check the length of the string, maybe you meant `strlen`?

Comment: BTW, it's a brainless decision for your teachers to try teaching you (and your classmates, presumably) OOP while you can't even find the length of a string. Just sayin'.

Comment: Could be the first assignment in an introductory OOP class?  Nonetheless, this should be a pretty simple assignment for someone ready to start learning OOP.

Comment: @H2CO3 OUCH. Its a harsh reality I know. But I am trying to get better.

Comment: @user3075178 as I said, it's not your fault, but the school's.

Comment: @H2CO3 The length of a string is `str.size()`; I can't imagine that he's having trouble with this.  The problem seems more to be that he doesn't know how to access the individual characters (which is also a bit unacceptable), and convert them to numeric values.  (Of course, if they're actually using `char const*` without already having learned `std::string`, there's something seriously wrong with the course.)

Comment: @JamesKanze It seems to me that they do. OP is trying to check the length of a `const char *` by calling `atoi()` on it, which suggests me that the teacher hasn't even talked about `strlen()`.

Comment: @H2CO3 That's not my impression (but there's no way to know).  My impression is that he is trying first to get the numeric value of the string, and then wants an algorithm to work on it.  Probably not the best solution (but quite doable, as well, if you use an integral type large enough to hold 13 digits).

Comment: @H2CO3 And one would hope that the teacher hadn't mentioned `strlen`, which doesn't have any place in a C++ course, at least not a beginner's one.

Answer (score 2):

You can start with a for loop which increments itself by 2 for each execution:

```
for (int i = 1, len = strlen(str); i < len; i += 2)
{
    int digit = str[i] - '0';

    // do something with digit
}
```

The above is just an example though...

Answer (score 0):

Since the question was tagged as `C++` *(Not `C`, so I suggest other answerers to not solve this using C libraries, please. Let us getting OP's C++ knoweledge in the right way since the beggining)*, and is an OOP class I'm going to solve this with the C++ way: **Use the `std::string` class**:

```
bool is_valid( const std::string& str )
{
    if( str.size() == 13 )
    {
        for( std::size_t i = 0 ; i < 13 ; i += 2 )
        {
            int digit = str[i] - '0';

            //Do what you wan't with the digit
        }
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if it's EAN, you have to process every digit, not just
every other one.  In fact, all you need to do is a weighted sum
of the digits; for EAN-13, the weigths alternate between 1 and
3, starting with three.  The simplest solution is probably to
put them in a table (i.e. `int weigt[] = { 1, 3, 1, 3... };`,
and iterate over the string (in this case, using an index rather
than iterators, since you want to be able to index into
`weight` as well), converting each digit into a numerical value
(`str[i] - '0'`, if `isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(str[i])`
is true; if it's false, you haven't got a digi.), then 
multiplying it by the running total.  When you're finished, if
the total, modulo 10, is 0, it's correct.  Otherwise, it isn't.

You certainly don't want to use `atoi`, since you don't want the
numerical value of the string; you want to treat each digit
separately.

Just for the record, professionally, I'd write something like:

```
bool
isValidEAN13( std::string const& value )
{
    return value.size() == 13
        && std::find_if(
                value.begin(),
                value.end(),
                []( unsigned char ch ){ return !isdigit( ch ); } )
            == value.end()
        && calculateEAN13( value ) == value.back() - '0';
}
```

where `calculateEAN13` does the actual calculations (and can be
used for both generation and checking).  I suspect that this 
goes beyond the goal of the assignment, however, and that all
your teacher is looking for is the `calculateEAN13` function,
with the last check (which is why I'm not giving it in full).